# Difference between Oracle CURSOR and Azure SQL CURSOR function

Tags: sql-server, oracle, function, azure

I'm currently translating Oracle SQL functions into Azure SQL functions. The majority of the logic has been translated successfully, but I wanted to make sure I didn't miss any 'gotcha's' along the way.

In our Oracle system, we heavily use cursors in functions for performance and to ensure only 1 output, but [from this article](https://www.quora.com/How-different-are-Oracle-cursors-and-SQL-Server-cursors), I don't think I need to use the cursors in Azure SQL.

**Is there any issue with using a SELECT statement and TOP(1) in Azure to replace Oracle's CURSOR functionality?**

Code already works. Just wanted an additional perspective.

ORACLE SQL CODE:

```
CREATE function GetName(id_in IN varchar2) return varchar2 is

  cursor name ( id_in varchar2) is
    select <query>
      from <table>
     where <condition>
  name_rec varchar2(90) := null;

begin
  open name ( id_in );
  fetch name into name_rec;
      close name;
      return name_rec;
    end getname;
    else null;
  end if;
  close name;
  return name_rec;
end getname;
```

AZURE SQL CODE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GETNAME] 
( 
@ID_IN varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name varchar(max);
    SET @name= 
        (SELECT TOP(1) 
        <query>
        FROM <table>
        WHERE <condition>
        )
    return @name;
end
```

Comment: In SQL Server world, one NEVER uses cursors for performance. Cursors are TERRIBLE for performance.

And the "Gotcha" with using TOP in SQL Server is that you need to always include an ORDER BY, because without an ORDER BY, the 'top 1' isn't deterministic. So be explicit, even if it's just "ORDER BY <primary key>"

Comment: @pmbAustin is correct. I would guess that you wouldn't need `TOP 1` here though, unless you expected your `WHERE` condition to return more than 1 value. Also, I would expect the `@ID_IN` to *not* be a `VARCHAR(max)`. That's huge.

Comment: Sweet thanks. I added the TOP (1) to mimic the original code. Don't expect it to ever return 2 rows. Good point about the varchar(max) as well. Gonna update that.